# When TextToSpeech synthesizeToFile is completed?

Tags: java, android, logging, listener, text-to-speech

I need to call `synthesizeToFile` to create some audio files and I need to know when it finished creating all these files, in order to inform the user.

I already read other questions but I did not found one that works for me or the question was related to the `speak` functionality.

build.gradle (module: app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.appName"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextToSpeech tts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        Map<String, String> mapFilesToGenerate = new HashMap<>();

        List<MyEnum> listMyEnum = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values()));
        for (MyEnum e : listMyEnum)
        {
            File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/" + e.id);
            if (!file.exists())
            {
                mapFilesToGenerate.put(e.id, e.name);
            }
        }

        // this Toast will be shown
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Preparing audio files...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("testTTS", "Preparing audio files...");

        tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status)
            {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
                {
                    tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener()
                    {
                        // **********
                        // all Toasts and Logs in this block aren't showed
                        // **********

                        @Override
                        public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "generating audio files... (" + mapFilesToGenerate.size() + " files)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d("testTTS", "generating audio files... (" + mapFilesToGenerate.size() + " files)");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Generation complete.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d("testTTS", "Generation complete.");
                            new Thread()
                            {
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        public void run()
                                        {

                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "TTS Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            Log.d("testTTS", "TTS Completed");
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }.start();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                            Log.d("testTTS", "error.");
                        }
                    });

                    generateAudioFiles("en", mapFilesToGenerate);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TTS inizialization failed! status = " + status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

private void generateAudioFiles(Map<String, String> mapFilesToGenerate)
{
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mapFilesToGenerate.entrySet())
    {
        saveAudioFileWithTTS("en", entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
    }
}

private boolean saveAudioFileWithTTS(String text, String pathFileName)
{
    int returnCode = -2;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        Locale locale = new Locale("en");

        tts.setLanguage(locale);

        tts.setPitch(1.2f);
        tts.setSpeechRate(0.8f);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            tts.setVoice(new Voice("nomeVoce", locale, Voice.QUALITY_VERY_HIGH, Voice.LATENCY_NORMAL, false, null));
        }

        String completePath = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + pathFileName;

        File fileToCreate = new File(completePath);
        returnCode = tts.synthesizeToFile
            (
                text
                , null
                , fileToCreate
                , pathFileName
            );
    }

    return returnCode == 0;
}
```

Why all Toast and Logs inside the `setOnUtteranceProgressListener` aren't showed?

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything I am not considering?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say that any of the following are possible:

A) Calling

```
generateAudioFiles("en", mapFilesToGenerate);
```

too soon after setting the UtteranceProgressListener.

B) Unnecessarily using 'new Thread()' when only

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "TTS Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
Log.d("testTTS", "TTS Completed");
```

is necessary.

C) Not using the above technique (B) in all UtteranceProgressListener callbacks  (since all these callbacks are called on a background thread, the toasts won't show unless you wrap the code like that).

D) The TTS Engine you are using simply doesn't accurately report completion of synthesizeToFile()

... You can also check the return value of synthesizeToFile() -- if it returns false, then the synthesis didn't take place at all and that would explain no callbacks being called.